# Edit view programmatically in linearlayout

Tags: java, android, view, android-linearlayout

This is my layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container1"       
        android:tag="1"
        //... >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:tag="1"
            //... />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container2"
        android:tag="2"
        //... >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:tag="2"
            //... />
    </LinearLayout>

    //...
```

It has 2 containers and one textview inside each one. Now, when I touch one button I need the container to exchange the textviews. To get this, this is my approach:

```
person1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
person2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);

place1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.place1);
place2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.place2);
```

-

```
place1.removeView(person1);
place2.removeView(person2);

place1.addView(person2);
place2.addView(person1);
```

But this is what I'm getting on the LogCat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the layouts contains a single `TextView` inside them. So instead of removing and adding views why don't you just switch the text between them? It would save your time and your performance would be better.

Comment: Well, have to say that what I'm really doing is use the drag&drop to move one textview to the other layout, so what I'm doing is trying to find the way to get the other textview into the first layout, this is, exchange booth. So changing their names is not an option

Comment: @masmic_87 Implement your drag and drop feature and when you get the event that user has dragged and dropped just switch the text, the effect would seem the same. In case it's not an option then you can use what Bhavesh has suggested.

Comment: I'll try what you say, to simplify the edittexts here just appear with the id and tag, but in my layout have several more params so before having to declare all of them porgrammatically I'm cosidering your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_ll_id);
TextView tv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_tv_id);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) tv.getParent();
parent.removeView(tv);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
//...
ll.addView(tv);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add textview at runtime in linearlayout rather than add textview in xml at compile time.

if you add textview at runtime it will not give you error.

```
linearLayout.removeAllViews();

final TextView person1 = new TextView(this);
linearLayout1.addView(person1);

final TextView person2 = new TextView(this);
linearLayout2.addView(person2);
```